# Mongodb - regex find and replace

Tags: regex, mongodb

I want to use regex to find and replace a comma (replace with nothing) within an array of fields. Fields are named document.0.Name through document.20.Name. How can I find and replace them all at once without searching first in 0 then 1 then 2, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

I've never coded in mongodb, but would it be possible to use a for loop?

```
for (var i = 0; i <= 20; i++) {
    # do your regex here on each file
}
```